# Distance between license plates

Tags: java

I have to get the distance in Java between any two license plate numbers like from AA-00-00 to 00-00-ZZ, no matter their format (it can also be like 00-AA-00). The numbers are increased before the letters and numbers go from 0-9 and letters from A to Z. 
The client code should be this one:

public class Main {

```
  public static void main(String [] s) {      

  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

  while(sc.hasNextLine()) { 

      Newplate mercedes = new Newplate(sc.next());

      Newplate bmw = new Newplate(sc.next());

   System.out.println(mercedes.dist(bmw)); 
   }

   sc.close(); 
}

}
```

Does anyone knows how can I get the distance between this formats? Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there some question here beyond base 36 math?

Comment: Yes, i also had to do the sum of the number of combinations for each character alphanumeric but i only realised after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be 0-9 = 10 characters + A-Z = 26 Characters so instead of being base 10 its base 36

You could put each character in an array and map to it value 1 through 36

Then to get the value of the plate you multiply starting at the rightmost character

```
Char value * 1 +
Char value * 36 +
Char Value * (36*36) +
Char value * (36 * 36 *36) + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with base-36 math,

```
"0": 0,
"1": 1,
...
"A": 10,
"B": 11,
...
"Z": 35,
"10": 36,
"11": 37,
...
```

To convert from an integer to its base-36 representation you can do something like:

```
>>> def num2str36(N):
...     W = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
...     S = ''
...     while N > 0:
...             d = N % 36
...             S = S + W[d]
...             N = N // 36
...     return ''.join(reversed(S))
... 
>>> num2str36(0)
''
>>> num2str36(1)
'1'
>>> num2str36(35)
'Z'
>>> num2str36(36)
'10'
>>> num2str36(1000000)
'LFLS'
>>> num2str36(1000010)
'LFM2'
```